# Is there an XML equivalent to GeoJSON?

Tags: geojson, gml, xml

In my web application, I am retrieving geospatial data from a server backend (Java) to the browser frontend (JavaScript). I am considering two options of how to serialize the data in this communication - `XML` and `JSON`.

`XML` seems to be a faster option as it can be deserialized by browser itself (into a documentElement), while `JSON` must be deserialized by a JavaScript library. On the other hand, there is a standard for storing geospatial data in `JSON` (`GeoJSON`), so using `JSON` would make the application more standard-compliant.

So my question is, is there an `XML` equivalent to `GeoJSON`? I found out that the term `GeoXML` has already been coined, but [it is the name of a library](http://www.dyasdesigns.com/geoxml/), not a format standard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GML, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_Markup_Language

KML, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language

GML / KML  difference

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_Markup_Language#GML_and_KML